# early this morning vs earlier this morning

Tags: differences

> I went jogging earlier this morning.

I think this just means he went jogging in the morning but it could be late in the morning.

> I went jogging early this morning.

I think this means he went jogging when it was very early in the morning.

Am I right?

<sub>PS: I wrote the sentence myself to contrast early and earlier.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I went running earlier this morning.

It is still morning as we speak! I went running at some point before now, during this morning.

> I went running early this morning.

It can be afternoon or evening by now. But at some point this morning, you went running. You either went earlier than you usually go (say, 8 insted of 11), or you can mean that you went at a tiem that normal people would consider early (5?).

The difference is a bit more outspoken if you substitute *week* for morning: "Early this week" (or last week, or next week!) means probably Monday or Tuseday.

"Earlier this week" means somewhere in the current week, before now. So if today is Saturday, "earlier this week" could be Thursday.

Comment: My first question on stack exchange and you sir, totally made my day. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

Well, for me you are almost right.

"Early this morning" is more accurate than "Earlier this morning"

"early" refers to the morning, when "earlier" refers to the present time ("this morning" serving as a precision)

Answer (score 0):

You have it exactly right. They are different. "earlier" could mean either 'anytime before now', or 'more early than usual', and as you say, it could actually have been quite late as long as it was still morning and before the present sentence is uttered. "Early" means exactly that: there is an implied shared definition of "early" (bit of a fiction in reality) and that is when you ran.